# Discussion tag in meta

Tags: support, meta

I've noticed that there is a tag for "discussion" in meta. I know that discussion posts are not recommended for SO, are the rules different for meta?

Comment: Yes. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work

Answer (score 8):

MSO exists to encourage new ideas and solutions to problems on SO, as well as general support for how the site works. A `[discussion]` on MSO allows users, moderators and the SO team to work through problems and evaluate new ideas.

SO was designed to find quality answers to *answerable* questions, specifically discouraging discussions.

Arguably, the SO software is not the best tool for meta discussion. However, if the team were to have implemented MSO using phpBB or some other forum platform, it would have been the mother of all ironies.

All things considered, I think it has all worked out pretty well.